# i don't know why the terminal keep running and doesn't show any result

Tags: python, loops, variables, while-loop

this is the exercise that work i on:
You have graduated from MIT and now have a great job! You move to the San Francisco Bay Area and
decide that you want to start saving to buy a house.  As housing prices are very high in the Bay Area,
you realize you are going to have to save for several years before you can afford to make the down
payment on a house. In Part A, we are going to determine how long it will take you to save enough
money to make the down payment given the following assumptions:

1. Call the cost of your dream home total_cost.
2. Call the portion of the cost needed for a down payment portion_down_payment. For
   simplicity, assume that portion_down_payment = 0.25 (25%).
3. Call the amount that you have saved thus far current_savings. You start with a current
   savings of $0.
4. Assume that you invest your current savings wisely, with an annual return of r (in other words,
   at the end of each month, you receive an additional current_savings*r/12 funds to put into
   your savings – the 12 is because r is an annual rate). Assume that your investments earn a
   return of r = 0.04 (4%).
5. Assume your annual salary is annual_salary.
6. Assume you are going to dedicate a certain amount of your salary each month to saving for
   the down payment. Call that portion_saved. This variable should be in decimal form (i.e. 0.1
   for 10%).
7. At the end of each month, your savings will be increased by the return on your investment,
   plus a percentage of your monthly salary (annual salary / 12).
   Write a program to calculate how many months it will take you to save up enough money for a down
   payment. You will want your main variables to be floats, so you should cast user inputs to floats.
   1
   Your program should ask the user to enter the following variables:
8. The starting annual salary (annual_salary)
9. The portion of salary to be saved (portion_saved)
10. The cost of your dream home (total_cost)
    Hints
    To help you get started, here is a rough outline of the stages you should probably follow in writing your
    code:
    ● Retrieve user input. Look at input() if you need help with getting user input. For this problem set,
    you can assume that users will enter valid input (e.g. they won’t enter a string when you expect
    an int)
    ● Initialize some state variables. You should decide what information you need.  Be careful about
    values that represent annual amounts and those that represent monthly amounts.
    Try different inputs and see how long it takes to save for a down payment.  Please make your
    program print results in the format shown in the test cases below.

Test Case 1

Enter your annual salary: 120000,
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: .10,
Enter the cost of your dream home: 1000000,
Number of months: 183

Test Case 2

Enter your annual salary: 80000,
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: .15,
Enter the cost of your dream home: 500000,
Number of months: 105,
this is my code:

---

---

```
#variables and inputs:
current_savings=0
r=0.04
additional_current_savings=current_savings*r/12
annual_salary=float(input("Enter your annual salary: "))
portion_saved=float(input("Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: "))
total_cost=float(input("Enter the cost of your dream home: "))
portion_down_payment=0.25*total_cost
monthly_salary=annual_salary / 12
new_total_saving=0
number_of_months=0
total_saving=portion_saved+current_savings+additional_current_savings
#a program to calculate how many months it will take someone to save up enough money for a down payment:
while new_total_saving != portion_down_payment :
 new_total_saving += total_saving
 number_of_months += 1
print(f"Number of months: {number_of_months}")
```

this is the expected output:
Enter your annual salary: 120000
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: .10
Enter the cost of your dream home: 1000000
Number of months: 183

i know that my program isn't all encompassing,but it should have solved atleast test case 1.
i don't know why the terminal keep running without any result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your sample input, expected output and actual output.   It probably keeps on running because ```new_total_saving``` will never be the same as ```portion_down_payment```; but that's just my speculation as I don't know what you entered.

Comment: Also be aware of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: Instead of checking for the exact match ```new_total_saving != portion_down_payment```, you are better off checking ```new_total_saving < portion_down_payment``` since we would be dealing with floats. So whenever the saving crosses the down payment amount, it will break the loop

Comment: Fwiw, there is still an issue with your code.  When I run it with the test cases, the ```number_of_months``` is invalid.  Your ```portion_saved``` value isn't correct.

Comment: Further, in your loop, you are not taking account two things
1. You are not adding the monthly savings from the salary
2. You are not adding the monthly interest on investments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code, the while loop condition was `new_total_saving != portion_down_payment`. The issue here is that due to the nature of floating-point arithmetic, it's possible that `new_total_saving` never exactly equals `portion_down_payment` due to small precision errors. Hence, the loop will run indefinitely because `new_total_saving` will never be exactly equal to `portion_down_payment`. So, your terminal seems running because the loop never terminated.

What you really want according to your problem statement is that your loop should run until `new_total_saving` becomes greater than or equal to `portion_down_payment` so that you have **at least** the down payment money  saved. To fix this issue, you should use a less than inequality operand (`<`).

Additionally in your program,

1. Remove unnecessary variables (`additional_current_savings`, `new_total_saving`, and `total_saving`)
2. Modify the loop condition to check if `current_savings` is less than `portion_down_payment`.
3. Update the calculation of `current_savings` within the loop to properly account for both investment returns and monthly savings as following:

```
while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
    # Update current_savings with investment return
    current_savings += current_savings * r / 12
    
    # Add monthly savings from salary to current_savings
    current_savings += monthly_salary * portion_saved
    
    # Increment the number of months
    number_of_months += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm adding the monthly portion of the salary that user would save and the monthly interest on his investment.

```
# input
annual_salary = float(input("Enter your annual salary: "))
current_savings = float(input("Enter your current savings: "))
portion_saved = float(input("Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: "))
total_cost = float(input("Enter the cost of your dream home: "))

# variables
r = 0.04
portion_down_payment = 0.25 * total_cost
monthly_salary = annual_salary / 12
months = 0

# logic
while current_savings < portion_down_payment:
    months += 1
    current_savings += current_savings * r/12 + portion_saved * monthly_salary

print(f"Number of months: {months}")
```

result

```
Enter your annual salary: 120000
Enter your current savings: 0
Enter the percent of your salary to save, as a decimal: 0.1
Enter the cost of your dream home: 1000000
Number of months: 183

Process finished with exit code 0
```